# Always call JSON.stringify on post data for jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Or any other function to preprocess your data for that matter :)

Because of my server side framework, I always need to call JSON.stringify before sending my data - unnecessary boilerplate, that you can forget to add.

Right now I have:

```
$.ajax({
    [...]
    data: JSON.stringify({ someData: self.someData }),
    [...]
});
```

I would prefer:

```
$.ajax({
    [...]
    data: { someData: self.someData },
    [...]
});
```

I've looked into ajaxSetup, but can't find a solution for this, so far...

**Update**

For a reason why I need this, see the following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140940/jquery-problem-with-sending-json-data-to-asp-net-webmethod). I could fix this on the serverside, but for now I'm looking for a way to fix this on the clientside.

Comment: If the content-type of your request is JSON, you shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: You might be serializing your data at the server unwantedly.. Happened to me sometime back..or you might have to check your `responseType`..if its got "text" or "html" this might happen

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup({ contentType: 'json' });`

Comment: Setting the content type does not transform the data to that type of data. If it's an object, jQuery will still pass it to `$.param`, thus turning it into serialized data such as `somedata=foobar&someotherdata=barfoo`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, there is no built-in way to pre-process your data from an object to JSON. However, you can use `ajaxSetup` and a `beforeSend` to do it for you.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR,options){
        if ( options.contentType == "application/json" && typeof options.data != "string" ) {
            options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
        }
    }
});
```

Now just make sure to set your `contentType` to `application/json` on requests that need to send json to the server so that it will get caught by the if statement.

Comment: Seems promising - only does jQuery seem to do some serializing stuff before calling beforeSend. Therefore calling some functions() defined on my model someData - I'm using Knockout.js. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Ah, right, because beforeSend happens AFTER jquery converts the object to string data. beforeSend won't work in this case unless you also use `processData: false`

Comment: processData: false works for me, and is an offer I can afford :) Thanks!

Comment: This would likely be better done as an ajax prefilter.

Answer (score 3):

Here an alternative approach that uses a [jQuery.prefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/):

```
$.ajaxPrefilter("json", function(options, originalOptions) {
  options.data = JSON.stringify(originalOptions.data || null);
  options.contentType = "application/json" // content type of *request*
});

$.ajax({
  data: {foo: [1,2,3]},
  dataType: "json" // expected content type of *response* (must match prefilter, above!)
  [...]
});
```

Because prefilters match on the `dataType` option, we have to set it manually in our `$.ajax` request. If the `dataType` matches the prefilter ("json") then before the request is sent, it will convert the `data` object to a string, and set the `contentType` header to match ("application/json").

Keep in mind that this a a *global* change that will impact ALL future `$.ajax` requests with `dataType: "json"`!

Comment: Thank you! You can wrap the innards of the prefilter function with `if(/POST|PUT|PATCH/.test(options.type)) { ... }` to only affect requests with a body.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [jQuery.prefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) function i use (it's better than the beforeSend approach), it will match any datatype, and will serialize any object in a post or put request.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, org) {
    var rtype = options.type.toLowerCase();
    if ((rtype === "post" || rtype === "put") && org.data !== null && typeof org.data === 'object') {
        options.data = JSON.stringify(org.data);
    }
});
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

User Jquery.getJSON().You can directly get json data.

```
$.getJSON('', function(data) {

//you can use data.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/