# Setting `processData: false` in jQuery + Datatables appends unknown stuff to URL of my Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

In following **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17216158/99971)**, I wanted to convert all my Ajax requests to `JSON` automatically and it's been working fine.

However, I've noticed that sometimes jQuery adds a mysterious `&[object%20Object]` at the end of the URL right before the anti-cache parameter (`_=1472476048876` for example), because I also have `cache: false` set.

When I change processData to be true, the mysterious part disappears. Anyone have any ideas why? I'm using `jQuery 2.1.4`.

**Edit**: I've noticed that the error only is produced when I make an Ajax call via Datatables `.load()` API. Has anyone else had this issue?

**Edit 2**: In response to @war10ck 's great answer, to clarify, I'm making a GET request but I'm not sending any data with it. I create the URL by hand and thus I think that Datatables is adding some data (even an empty object maybe) to my request which is getting turned into `[object%20Object]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the root of the problem. Deep in the internals of Datatables, in a function called `_fnBuildAjax`, even if you don't give anything as a `data` parameter, there are two lines that do the following:

```
var tmp = {};
// ...if data is empty...
data = tmp;
```

This ends up passing an empty object to the jQuery ajax call further down near the bottom of the same function. Normally jQuery would take this empty object and not change the call, but since `processData` is `false`, jQuery appends it to the URL (being a GET request after all) and turns it into `[object%20Object]` even though it is **an empty object**. This only happens with Datatables because elsewhere in my code I am giving simply not specifying a `data` parameter for an Ajax call and jQuery is smart enough simply not to append anything to the URL, but when it sees an empty object it doesn't know what to do and appends it as is. I hope this helps future programmers debug this edge case :). Thanks again to @war10ck for his explanation.

Comment: Well researched! +1 That's an interesting find. I feel like that could be handled better and/or differently in the future. You may want to submit a request to the developer(s) to get his/her thoughts on it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're making a `GET` request, whether via your own jQuery call or via Datatables. In a `GET` request, parameters are sent to the server via the url query string:

```
example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Part of the abstraction that the jQuery does behind the scenes in `$.ajax()` is to convert the data that you pass in via the `data` parameter in the object to a suitable format for the request. In the case of a standard `GET` request with content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, it's a string of key/value paris separated by ampersands. This works great when the data you're working with in your application is a JavaScript object. As an example:

```
var obj = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
};

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "www.example.com",
    data: obj
});
```

Results in the called url being:

```
www.example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2
```

as jQuery does the data conversion behind the scenes for you. ***However***, according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **`data` parameter:**
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

and

> **`processData` parameter**:
>
> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

setting `processData` to false will prevent the default data manipulation and conversion from an `Object` format to a suitable url `String`. Instead, the data will be converted using the `.toString()` native method on the `Object` prototype by the browser automatically when the url is called. Here is how that appears:

```js
var obj = {};
alert(obj.toString());
```

So now, since the default processing is off, your data example becomes the following:

```
var obj = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
};

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "www.example.com",
    data: obj,
    processData: false
});
```

Results in the called url being:

```
www.example.com?[object%20Object]
```

like you see above in the mini-code snippet with the extra addition of `%20` as the url encoding value of a space, as noted in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) and updated by [RFC 6874](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6874) and [RFC 7320](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7320).

**Edit to elaborate on why Datatables is causing the above issue:**

To further address your question of why it only appears to happen with [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables) `.load()`, it appears the *datatables* [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) object is a wrapper for jQuery's default `$.ajax()`. In the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for `$.ajax()` the `type` parameter is defaulting to `GET` when not directly specified. So *datatables* initiates a `GET` request and, with `processData` set to `false`, the above scenario happens.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, it's a great help. I do already understand all that you have said, but my problem is that there is no data being sent with the request and I create the URL by hand so there should be nothing added. You are right, in your example about `obj` becoming `[object%20Object]` but the question is: **where** is the data coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys! In addition to your researches that helped me to solve my problem I would like to share the corresponding solution.

In my case the problem is a call similar to

http://server/dir/resource.en.json?_=1510566367817

resulted in 
http://server/dir/[object%20Object]?_=1510566367817

The main hint is daveslab' one regarding to handling of empty objects.

In combination with a multi language project envinronment I came around thinking about missing resource files. That ist where the empty object joins the game because the relevant resource.fr.json file was missing.

In this case it doesn't matter if processData is set to false or true.
I checked both.

Summary

Json files called by client-side code but missing on the server can cause the same issue.

Client facts in my case:
I use jquery 3.2.1 AJAX Get-Service with the following configuration

```
{
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,    
    cache: false,
    processData: false 
}
```