# Passing parameter to WebMethod with jQuery Ajax getting error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, serialization

I am using a web method and ajax call but can't get it right with parameters?

I have worked though a number of fixings but non have been able to solve my problem?

I need to pass though a string and have my web method return a data table, why is it necessary to pass it through as a json?

Here is the ajax call:

```
var jsdata = '{category:' + category + '}';
var jstext = JSON.stringify(jsdata, null, 2);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "GIFacRequest.aspx/GetSubCategories",
  data: jstext ,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (dtSubCategory) {
        PopulateSubCategoryDD(dtSubCategory);
      },
      error: function (response) {
         $('body', document).html(response.responseText);
      }
  });
```

And my webmethod:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
public static DataTable GetSubCategories(string category)
{
}
```

The error i'm getting is as follows:

> "Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to
>   type
>   \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\u0027","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object
>   o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Object& convertedObject)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object
>   o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError,
>   Object& convertedObject)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer
>   serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String
>   input)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext
>   context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData
>   methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"

Comment: Try with just `jsdata` in ajax

Comment: @SridharR i then get the error message: :"Invalid JSON primitive: Maintenance." Where Maintenance is my variable.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736058/passing-parameter-to-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax?

Comment: @SridharR I have seen that post and it did not provide any answers.

Comment: One answer explain the problem thats why it get up votes

Comment: Refer this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140940/jquery-problem-with-sending-json-data-to-asp-net-webmethod

Answer (score 1):

your variable params `var jsdata = '{category:' + category + '}'` is a string.

So the line: `JSON.stringify(jsdata, null, 2);`, is redundant (or it should be). Just set data: jsdata,

Try with this code

```
var jsdata = '{category:' + category + '}';
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "GIFacRequest.aspx/GetSubCategories",
  data: jsdata ,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (dtSubCategory) {
        PopulateSubCategoryDD(dtSubCategory);
      },
      error: function (response) {
         $('body', document).html(response.responseText);
      }
  });
```

Comment: Removing that line i then get the error message, "Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: Maintenance." Where Maintenance is the variable i was trying to pass in.

Comment: Thanks :) that did it for me :)